# Unable to add window exception while showing a progress bar

Tags: android, listview, android-progressbar

**AIM** I have an activity with a list view and a few buttons and a few extra stuff. What I want is to populate this list view with custom adapter when the activity starts. As it takes time to generate this custom adapter I wanted to add a progress bar, so that user is not forced to stare at the unresponsive-screen. When done, dismiss this progress bar and show the activity as it is supposed to be.

**WHAT I DID - "*CODE*"**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
// all initialization done here properly
new ProgressTask(this).execute("");
}

public class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    public ProgressTask(ScanInboxActivity activity) {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity.getApplicationContext());
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

        /** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Scan start");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();               
        }
        populateList();
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
        init(); // tasks to be performed- no error here
        scanSms(); // tasks to be performed- no error here
        return true;
    }
}
```

I get following Exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.ScanInboxActivity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:509)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
at com.example.ScanInboxActivity$ProgressTask.<init>(ScanInboxActivity.java:212)
at com.example.ScanInboxActivity.onCreate(ScanInboxActivity.java:59)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
... 11 more
```

Please note that when I write this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// all initialization done here properly
init();
scanSms();
populateList();
}
```

Things work fine, though the activity which starts this activity hangs for a moment. I don't want this to happen.

Please suggest what to do. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** scanSms() uses context. I can not eliminate use of context because it is used in a function (in a different class) called in scanSms(), which is also called from other activities around the application

Comment: are you using tabhost or anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public ProgressTask(ScanInboxActivity activity) {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Scan start");
        this.dialog.show();
    }
```

EDITED:

```
public class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        /** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */
        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        public ProgressTask(MainMenuActivity activity) {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Scan start");
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();               
            }
            //populateList();
        }

        protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
            //init(); // tasks to be performed- no error here
            //scanSms(); // tasks to be performed- no error here
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, pretty much the same. Difference is `at com.example.ScanInboxActivity$ProgressTask.<init>(ScanInboxActivity.java:219)` now. i.e. changes the line number where I am calling this.dialog.show()

Comment: I've updated my post by adding full code. I tried this code in activity in my project and it worked. May be you make little typo or mistake? Compare again, please

Comment: It worked. Thankyou. I don't know where the problem was with my code. I will be checking it out. I may have made a typo somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that the methods `init()` and `scanSms()` which you put in `doInBackground()`, makes use of `Context`. If this is so then this might be the cause, as the `doInBackground()` should not use the context.

Try to do the initialization in `onPreExecute()` which is invoked on UI thread, and only the heavy stuff in `doInBackground()`.

Comment: only scanSms() uses context. I tried putting init in onPreExecute(). It does not work that way.

Answer (score -2):

```
  class asytask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
        {
            ProgressDialog dialog ;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPreExecute();
                dialog  = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
                dialog.show();
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

//use your backgournd process
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                dialog.dismiss();

 //  visible process
            }
        }
```

Comment: Make some effort to paste code with `Code` format. Your code is massive.